# How do you call a PDF file that is in a folder and display it on a webpage by entering the folder name?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm a beginner learning HTML, CSS, PHP and javascript as I go. I am currently coding an HTML page where you can enter the name of a folder in a text box. When submitted, it displays a PDF file located in the entered folder. I tried searching online but couldn't find what I wanted specifically.

Right now, all i can do is embed a PDF file to the web page by linking it to the specific file (below). This isn't practical as I'll have many more folders in the future.

```
<object data="FFF.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
```

in a nutshell, what I need is for it to work like this :

```
<form action="page.php" method=post>
    <input type=text name="pdf">
</form>

<?php
    <object data="uploads/$_POST[pdf]/FFF.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>
?>
```

Since that is not possible, I'd appreciate an alternative. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change <object data="uploads/$_POST[pdf]/FFF.pdf" to <object data="uploads/<?php echo $_POST['pdf'];?>/FFF.pdf"

Comment: i tagged because i thought calling the file would need PHP

Comment: `<?php if (isset($_POST['pdf'])) echo "<object data='uploads/{$_POST['pdf']}/FFF.pdf' type='application/pdf'></object>"; ?>`

Comment: `calling the file` - do you mean loading? you don't "call" files in javascript, you call functions

Answer (score 0):

**First of all: Don`t do that. It's a security risk:** By including a path, a part of a path, or a filename in your POST data, you risk someone being able to manipulate that POST-call, and accessing things on your server that they should not have access to.

**A better option:** List your files and their file-paths in a database, and use a unique but hard to guess ID for each file (typically a *GUID*). Where you currently pass a part of the path to the file as a part of the POST call, you should instead pass that id. The page that is responsible for presenting the PDF can then use that ID to look up that ID, find out which file it refers to, and get the correct path to it from the DB.

---

*Reservations: You said your're creating:*

> "..an HTML page where you can enter the name of a folder in a text box..."

*I'm not sure exactly what your are building here, so perhaps what your doing is perfectly fine in your context. On a general basis howerver, you should try to follow the principle of not exposing any details about the file structure on the server.*

Comment: no. this is just a hobby :) I use HTML and PHP as an interactive database of sorts to learn both of those languages. I was just interested and curious. Thank you, I'll keep that in mind as I progress, i think its a good principle to follow for anyone learning, regardless.